# How to assign value to PHP variable from daterangepicker

Tags: php, variables, daterangepicker

How I can retrieve the date from a script's `daterangepicker` to a PHP variable?

Here is my JS code:

```
var startDate;
var endDate;

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker(
       {
          startDate: moment().subtract('days', 29),
          endDate: moment(),
          minDate: '01/01/2018',
          maxDate: '12/31/2039',
          dateLimit: { days: 60 },
          showDropdowns: true,
          showWeekNumbers: true,
          timePicker: false,
          timePickerIncrement: 1,
          timePicker12Hour: true,
          ranges: {
             'დღეს': [moment(), moment()],
             'გუშინ': [moment().subtract('days', 1), moment().subtract('days', 1)],
             'ბოლო 7 დღე': [moment().subtract('days', 6), moment()],
             'ბოლო 30 დღე': [moment().subtract('days', 29), moment()],
             'მიმდინარე თვე': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
             'წინა თვე': [moment().subtract('month', 1).startOf('month'), moment().subtract('month', 1).endOf('month')]
          },
          opens: 'left',
          buttonClasses: ['btn btn-default'],
          applyClass: 'btn-small btn-primary',
          cancelClass: 'btn-small',
          format: 'YYY-MM-DD',
          separator: ' დან ',
          locale: {
              applyLabel: 'გაფილტვრა',
              fromLabel: 'დან',
              toLabel: 'მდე',
              customRangeLabel: 'სხვა თარიღები',
              daysOfWeek: ['კვ', 'ორშ', 'სამ', 'ოთხ', 'ხუთ', 'პარ','შაბ'],
              monthNames: ['იანვარი', 'თებერვალი', 'მარტი', 'აპრილი', 'მაისი', 'ივნისი', 'ივლისი', 'აგვისტო', 'სექტემბერი', 'ოქტომბერი', 'ნოემბერი', 'დეკემბერი'],
              firstDay: 1
          }
       },
       function(start, end) {
        console.log("Callback has been called!");
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
        startDate = start;
         endDate = end;    

       }
    );
    //Set the initial state of the picker label
    $('#reportrange span').html(moment().subtract('days', 29).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

    $('#saveBtn').click(function(){
        console.log(startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' - ' + endDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    });    
 });
```

I need the output value to be assigned to a PHP variable, like

```
 $startDate = var startDate;
```

...or something like this, so I can generate a SQL Query for filtering my table.

How can I do that?

Comment: If this is part of a form, how are you submitting it to the backend (PHP)?

Answer (score 1):

## You need to submit your object to the server.

On your daterangepicker object you need to add a name field.

Example:

```
<input type="text" name="reportrange" value="01/01/2018" />
```

PHP uses the name field to get values from a POST or GET value.

#### POST

If you submitted the value by POST you can grab the value like so:

```
$date = $_POST['reportrange'];
```

#### GET

If you submitted the value by GETyou can grab the value like so:

```
$date = $_GET['reportrange'];
```

NOTE: GET can be easily edited by the user. GET will create a query in the url like:

www.example.com/?reportrange=01/01/2018.

POST would hide that value.

You can look at examples here: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Comment: Okay if I add input method to my html, how script will give value to that input? must I change in script something? I added "<input type="text" name="from" value="" />" and "<input type="text" name="to" value="" />" in HTML but how to pass the values to it?

Comment: @AleksAndersonIT are the inputs on the same page?

Comment: I have <div class="table-responsive" id="reportrange" type="button" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 2px 15px; border: 3px solid #88ccfc; width: 20%"> this in HTML

Comment: @AleksAndersonIT you are going to need to ask another question on this website for your new question. Since I have solved your original issue could you click the check mark next to my answer above. Once you have created another question on this website you can past the link in this comment section.

Comment: Okay but the answer was not full I added this input but the main question was how to give value from script to variable, This answer does not respond my question